# Auto add a 'Custom Option' to a new product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add a Custom Option (a simple text field) as a default for all new products.

The products are built by importing a cvs via the

Import/Export/Import All Products

area of admin,

Using the configurable products does not work because the field is text that will be printed on the product.

Is it possible to get these products to import with the custom option automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Did you try to add an custom attribute for all the products(default empty) and then in the CSV add the attribute code as a column and fill in the value in rows?